# Samsung Galaxy Camera Android API - custom camera apps

Tags: android, camera, galaxy

Has anyone written any custom camera apps for the Samsung Galaxy Camera?
http://www.samsung.com/us/photography/digital-cameras/EK-GC100ZWAATT

I have one, but am having trouble adding more functionality than is included with any camera phone.  For example, I would like to control the shutter speed, as you can do with the camera app installed on the device.  I cannot figure out how to do that in the code.  I have read through the documentation for the camera API:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

That didn't help very much.  Also looked through the debugger output, which is rather cryptic.  Just wondering if anyone else is tinkering with this new camera.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but have not yet found anything informative. It's not even possible to change the ISO using the Camera API, which is possible on other Android Smartphones.

Comment: There's a mention on the Samsung Developer forum of an SDK, but there's no ETA or real guarantee of it actually appearing http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=220743

Comment: No way to set ISO, Metering, shutter, aperture, no WB Lock, no AE Lock... is it a camera for real?! Have a look at Camera.getParameters().flatten() - this is the only way i know to seek for parameters beyond standard APIs - in Galaxy Camera's flatten() i found nothing to hack!! What a pity!!

Comment: Hey, now I found some ways to work with parameters, see my answer below. Samsung seems to dislike Camera APIs level >=14, features look "unsupported", while using parameter.set() you may get them working.

Answer (score 3):

I also have the Samsung Galaxy camera and I am building an app for it as well.
I have tried to contact Samsung 10+ times and no-one there seems to even acknowledge that Samsumg manufactures the camera. To say nothing about getting any assistance on the api.

Comment: Tell me about it. 95% of at&t staff had no clue they sold the camera. Android seems to be taking hold on cameras now, I think I saw something about a polaroid with android.

Answer (score 3):

XDA helps!!

No need for APIs.

Here's the tip: `setParameters("mode", "m")` seems to be the key to start "hacking" parameters like iso, aperture, shutter, ...

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1997090&page=3#edit39210051

I haven't tried it yet, hack it and enjoy!

**EDIT**

Now i've tried it, i'm able to set ISO, smooth zoom, metering, AElock, WBlock...
The hard part is to make it all compatible with all other devices: most of the Galaxy Camera features are *hidden* in the `Parameters.flatten()` string, and others aren't there neither.

**Tip0**: always check `Parameters.flatten();` to see what's happening and use it to achieve the keywords you need (although it doesn't always help)

**Tip1**: for every feature you want to hack, try `set("mode", xxx)` before changing parameter (set xxx as one from ["smart-auto", "m", "program"] or test other mode values yourself)

**Tip2**: always use `myParam=Camera.getParameters();` before any other `myParam.set();` call.

**Tip3**: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712785/samsung-s4-zoom-does-not-support-smooth-zoom-issmoothzoomsupported-false/18886317?noredirect=1#comment37568162_18886317)'s how to go with smooth zoom (S4 zoom seems to have similar behaviours).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I told them that I was developing an Android app for their camera (EK-CG100) and I needed more info about some things. Their answer was something like "Sorry, but we don't have that system yet in our cameras". Are they kidding me? What kind of people do they have for answering emails. This is so sad.