# Samsung s4 zoom does not support smooth zoom isSmoothZoomSupported()==false

Tags: android, android-camera

I've tried to handle ZoomIn/ZoomOut at 's4 zoom' device in my camera record application. Because it does support only regular zoom, i.e `parameters.isZoomSupported()==true`, `parameters.isSmoothZoomSupported()==false`, I have used `parameters.setZoom(mZoomVal);` `mCamera.setParameters(parameters);` as usual.
Problem is Zoom is jerky, noisy and not smooth.
Does anybody know how to handle Zoom speed in 's4 zoom' as like it was done in Samsung camera app?

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.v("onKeyDown keyCode="+keyCode+" event="+event.toString());

    boolean handled = false;
    switch(keyCode){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FOCUS:
        setAutoFocus();
        handled = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:

        if(event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
            if (isRec()) {
                stopRec(1, 0);
            } else {
                startRec();
            }
        }

        handled = true;
        break;
    case 256: //KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA_ZOOM_RING_MOVE:
        handled = true;
        break;
    case 261: //KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA_ZOOM_RING_SPEED2
        handled = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ZOOM_IN:
        setZoomIn();
        //AutoFocus();
        handled = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ZOOM_OUT:
        setZoomOut();
        //AutoFocus();
        handled = true;
        break;
    }

    if(handled)
        Log.v("onKeyDown HANDLED!");
    else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    return handled;
}
public int setZoomIn(){
    if(mCamera == null){
        return 0;
    }

    Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Integer> zoom_list = parameters.getZoomRatios();
    if(mZoomVal >= mZoomMax)
        return zoom_list.get(mZoomMax);

    /*
    if(isAutoFocusing){
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        isAutoFocusing = false;
    }*/


    mZoomVal++;
    isFocused = false;

    parameters.setZoom(mZoomVal);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    mZoomVal = parameters.getZoom();

    return zoom_list.get(mZoomVal);
}

public int setZoomOut(){
    if(mCamera == null){
        return 0;
    }

    Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Integer> zoom_list = parameters.getZoomRatios();
    if(mZoomVal <= 0)
        return zoom_list.get(0);

    /*
    if(isAutoFocusing){
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        isAutoFocusing = false;
    }*/


    mZoomVal--;
    isFocused = false;

    parameters.setZoom(mZoomVal);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    mZoomVal = parameters.getZoom();

    return zoom_list.get(mZoomVal);
}

public void setAutoFocus(){
    if(mCamera == null){
        return;
    }

    if(isFocused)
        return;

    if(isAutoFocusing){
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        isAutoFocusing = false;
    }

    isAutoFocusing = true;
    mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            Log.v("onAutoFocus success="+success);
            isAutoFocusing = false;
            isFocused = success;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: The large optical zoom in the "camera" is probably the cause, it might have a more simple interface between the phone and the camera module. Might be that the zoom buttons on the device are linked straight to the optical zoom's engine and do not pass through the android OS.

Comment: The objective lens (optical zoom) correctly handled by onKeyDown, i.e if I comment setZoomIn,setZoomOut in the code, the objective (optical zoom) does not working. Obvious there is Samsung' workaround for speed control of the objective. Android SDK doesn't include Zoom speed interface.

Comment: Also I gathered info from Camera.Parameters parameters.flatten(); Values related to zoom are: zoom=0; zoom-supported=true; zoom-action=zoom-stop; factory-zoom-slope-check-data=-1,-1; zoom-ratios=100,120,140,160,180,220,310,420,560,790,1000; factory-zoom-range-check-data=-1,-1; zoom-ring=-1; max-zoom=10; curr_zoom_level=0; I've tried to change zoom-action=>zoom-start, zoom-ring etc, in fact, there was no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already found solution for Smooth control of Shutter lens on Samsung S4 Zoom device.
Set device in **smart mode**: `parameters.set("mode", "smart-auto");`

For **Zoom In start**: `parameters.set("zoom-action", "optical-tele-start");`

For **Zoom Out start**: `parameters.set("zoom-action", "optical-wide-start");`

For **Zoom action stop**: `parameters.set("zoom-action", "zoom-stop");`

**Shutter speed**: `parameters.set("zoom-speed", 1); //1,2,...`

Don't forget save parameters in the Camera instance `mCamera.setParameters(parameters);`

This works fine in my device, shutter now is silent and smooth. :)
Regards.

Comment: @j.c Did you get parameters = mCamera.getParameters(); first ? Also, use parameters.getInt("curr_zoom_level") in order to get current value of zoom value. Unfortunately, I haven't get Galaxy Camera device, only Z4, but I guess the method would be the same.

Comment: you're right, cannot say what i was doing wrong, but now it works! The only thing i mess with is the smart-auto mode: i cannot set focus, and often auto exposure locks... i was used to work with mode=pogram, i found it lets me do more things... have you tried?  Should i switch mode every time i set parameters?! how boring! It's also quite a big pain for compatibility (I would like it all works on every device too!)

Comment: How did you use these j.c.?  Only the first one worked for me to start zooming in, and it goes continuously.  Neither stopping or zooming back out worked thereafter.  Toggling "smart-auto" mode made no difference either. I'm working with the Galaxy Camera x21 zoom.

Answer (score 2):

Also, in order to get **current zoom value**, use this code:

```
            Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Integer> zoom_list = parameters.getZoomRatios();

            int val = 0;

            if(isSamsungS4Zoom){
                    //FOR S4 ZOOM
                    mZoomVal = parameters.getInt("curr_zoom_level");
                    val = zoom_list.get(mZoomVal);
            }else{
                    val = zoom_list.get(mZoomVal);
            }
```