# Zoom control for separate devices error

Tags: java, android, camera

In my camera layout there is 2 buttons for adjusting zoom parameter, one for increasing, and one for decreasing. On each button there is a OnClickListener. Before increasing/decreasing the zoom value I use  Camera.Parameters.isZoomSupported () function to check, is the device support zooming. On my Sony Z1 it works perfectly, but on my other device (Samsung Galaxy S), the fuction returns true, but the device can't zoom.

---

My code piece:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isZoomSupported()) {
                Camera cam = application.getCamera();
                if (cam != null) {
                    cam.stopPreview();
                    Parameters par = cam.getParameters();
                    int maxZoom = par.getMaxZoom();
                    int zoomValue = par.getZoom();
                    zoomErtek += 1;
                    if (zoomValue > maxZoom) {
                        zoomValue = maxZoom;
                    }
                    par.setZoom(zoomValue);
                    cam.setParameters(par);
                    cam.startPreview();
                }
            } else {
                toastShortWithCancel(getString(R.string.zoom_not_supported));
            }
        }
```

And my little isZoomSupported() function:

```
private boolean isZoomSupported() {
    Camera cam = application.getCamera();
    if (cam != null) {
        Parameters par = cam.getParameters();
        return par.isZoomSupported();
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, what is the problem with my zoom control? Is there any mistakes? My Samsung device runs Android 2.3.5, so I use API 8 for programming

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712785/samsung-s4-zoom-does-not-support-smooth-zoom-issmoothzoomsupported-false